# why ack packed don't have sequence number when three hand shark?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, ip, tcpdump

I use the tcpdump to watch the three-way handshake.
the **client** port is 51484  and **server** port is 9501

```
 //connect to server
//three-way handshake
51484 > 9501 : Flags [S], seq 2969626801
9501  > 51484: Flags [S.], seq 587835665, ack 2969626802,
51484 > 9501 : Flags [.], ack 587835666     // <-  why the ack don't 
                                            //    have sequence number ?

//close the connect 
51484 > 9501 : Flags [F.], seq 2969626802, ack 587835666
9501  > 51484: Flags [F.], seq 587835666, ack 2969626803
51484 > 9501 : Flags [.], ack 587835667
```

I know that : if condition permit , the ack packet will  be included in other's packet with some payload.But why the ack packet don't have sequence number when the payload is empty in the third step of  three-way handshake ?

My question is : **why the ack packet do not have sequence number in the third step of  three-way handshake ?**

Comment: It *does* have a sequence number. The number starting with 5. Off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a sequence number in a successful handshake communication, but actually, in this case, `tcpdump` is not showing the same by default.

You can enable the same by adding -vv or -vvv in your command for more verbose output from the available options. Below is the screenshot containing relevant verbose section description from the `tcpdump` manual:

[image: manual of tcpdump]

Comment: i close the connect several  minute later，i send nothing of data， so the sequence is  continues.

Comment: i just curious that why the third step do not take up a sequence.

Comment: In my opinion ,every packet should carray a sequence number.But  the third step of  sequence number.

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur -  Did you check the flags as I've highlighted in my answer?

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur - I noticed that you didn't reply to my question. Are you stuck at something? Please ask for clarification wherever you think it is required.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful As I'm reading the original question it's about sequence numbers in TCP headers while you are explaining acknowledgment numbers.

Comment: @SegFault - Yes, sorry! Now I see that I didn't focus well on the question. I'm modifying it, although you have already given the answer (unable to delete as this answer is marked as accepted)!

Answer (score 0):

The sequence number is not missing, it's just that, by default, tcpdump does not show it in all packets.

If you use something like `tcpdump -S -vvv` or a hexdump you will see that the expected sequence numbers are present in all of the segments.